# Compare a pass in function parameter and the array object property

Tags: javascript

Want to test if my find function can use a pass-in parameter to match an object property in the user array. I believe the problem is encounter in the if statement, and I am not sure this is the correct way to comparing the twos.

```
// member object 
function member(lname, fname, mname){
  return{
    lname: lname,  // object property
    fname: fname,
    mname: mname
  };
}

var user = [
    member('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename'),
    member('last', 'first', 'mname'),
    member('l', 'f', 'm'),
    member('ll', 'ff', 'mm')
];

function find(lname){
    for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
       if(lname === user[i][lname]){       
          return(console.log(lname));
       }else{
          return null;
       }
    }
}

console.log(find("last"));
```

The return is a null, and if I take out the else statement, it returns undefined.
Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me like `team` is not the same variable as `user` ?

Comment: where is _team_ ? also, don't return in the loop if you miss, keep looping to try again. also `team[i][lname]` should be `team[i].lname`

Comment: Yea, I forgot to change it. Fix it right now.

Comment: You could also do something [like this](http://jsbin.com/xazomimibu/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 1):

1. Team doesn't exist. It sounds like you're referring to the `user` array.
2. Instead of `user[i][lname]`, access the lname property by doing `user[i].lname`
3. If you return null in the else, you will not continue checking through the results. Your return should be outside the for loop, to indicate we've reached the end and there were no successful returns.

Working example:

```js
// member object 
function member(lname, fname, mname){
  return{
    lname: lname,  // object property
    fname: fname,
    mname: mname
  };
}

var user = [
    member('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename'),
    member('last', 'first', 'mname'),
    member('l', 'f', 'm'),
    member('ll', 'ff', 'mm')
];

function find(lname){
    for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
       if(lname === user[i].lname){       
          return "FOUND: " + lname;
       }
    }
  return null;
}

console.log(find("last"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why loop at all?

```
function find(lname){
  return user.filter(function(item){
      return item.lname === lname;
  });
}
```

The same but returning first hit:

```
function find(lname){
  return user.filter(function(item){
      return item.lname === lname;
  })[0];
}
```

Comment: If you always want the first match, you may want to put [0] at the end of the return value: })[0];

Comment: @FievelYaltsen Yes I know, that was my first thought, but then I thought the name of the function is `find` so it must do what it's saying it does.